# Generate Additional rows between values in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My DataFrame looks like

```
dataframe
   cbk_year  count
3         4      1
4         7      1
```

```
max_cbk_year_to_fill = 9
```

Desired Output

```
dataframe
   cbk_year  count
0         1      0
1         2      0
2         3      0
3         4      1
4         5      0
5         6      0
6         7      1
7         8      0
8         9      0
```

I want to add rows in **cbk_year** between 1 and 'max_cbk_year_to_fill' with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `reindex` trick:

```
(df.set_index('cbk_year')
   .reindex(range(1,max_cbk_year_to_fill+1), fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
```